# Ruby on rails tutorial $mate Gemfile problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm doing the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and am at 1.2.4 Bundler, where I have to do mate Gemfile but I have Windows and am using vim.

So what do I type instead of mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mate` is a command to open TextMate, a Mac editor. Just open Gemfile in your text editor of preference (it's in the root of your Rails project)

Comment: thanks this worked, I was able to open it from my root directory. Still unsuccessful at opening from the command prompt but i guess that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do vim GemFile or vi Gemfile. Let us know how you get on.